# How to sum up the time in SQL access

Tags: sql

So I need to add up the time from one of my queries. I have volunteers that have a startTime and an EndTime. I then used this code to calculate it through a query:

```
SELECT v.Name, Format(v.StartTime - v.EndTime, "hh:nn:ss") AS Time_Diffrence,
FROM VOLUNTEERS AS o, VOL_TASKS AS v, TASKS AS t
WHERE v.Taskcode = t.Taskcode
    AND v.Name = o.Name
ORDER BY 1;
```

Thus giving me the Time_Diffrence (noticed I just spelled difference wrong in my code) for each volunteer. But now I need to sum up the totals of the Time_Difference in another query. How would I go about doing this?

Heres the code I have so far but it doesn't even run :/

```
SELECT v.Name, Format(v.StartTime - v.EndTime, "hh:nn:ss") AS Time_Diffrence,     
Time_Diffrence = SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', WrkHrs)) 
FROM VOLUNTEERS AS o, VOL_TASKS AS v, TASKS AS t
WHERE v.Taskcode = t.Taskcode
    AND v.Name = o.Name
GROUP BY v.Name
ORDER BY 1 Asc;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Im using SQL inside access 2013. im confused on how to do datdiff. Should I do something like this:select DATEDIFF(day,2007-11-30,2007-11-20) AS NumberOfDays, DATEDIFF(hour,2007-11-30,2007-11-20) AS NumberOfHours, DATEDIFF(minute,2007-11-30,2007-11-20) AS NumberOfMinutes FROM test_table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT v.Name, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, v.StartTime, v.EndTime)) AS TimeDiffInSecs
FROM Volunteers AS v
INNER JOIN Vol_Tasks AS vt
    ON v.Name = vt.Name
INNER JOIN Tasks AS t
    ON v.TaskCode = t.TaskCode
GROUP BY v.Name
```

This should sum up all of the records for each user and give you an overall number of seconds worked. (I didn't do minutes, because you can lose some time from the rounding)

Comment: for some reason when I run it I get a Syntax error for v.Name = vtName  INNER JOIN Tasks AS t ON v.TaskCode = t.TaskCode. let me post my code after I fixed it some to match how my tables are assigned. heres my code: SELECT v.Name, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, v.StartTime, v.EndTime)) AS TimeDiffInSecs
FROM VOLUNTEERS AS v
INNER JOIN VOL_TASKS AS vt
    ON v.Name = vt.Name
INNER JOIN TASKS AS t
    ON vt.TaskCode = t.TaskCode
GROUP BY v.Name;

Comment: well, either you forgot the period (v.Name = vt.Name) or access doesn't like my use of vt for a variable name, change it to x or something different, it's just a temp name.

Comment: I changed it to x and I keep looking through to make sure I didn't miss a period. I did change v.TaskCode = t.TaskCode to x.TaskCode = t.TaskCode because my volunteers table doesn't have a TaskCode but idk if that will cause an error or not.

Comment: No it was actually how I had it typed in my tables! I also changed it too since I forgot I didn't have TaskCode in that table.

Comment: so the field names are wrong? or did it finally work?

Comment: I still keep getting a syntax error :/ I must be typing something wrong and just don't see it. When it shows the error message it also highlights SUM(DATE too idk if thats also a problem or its just where it sets the cursor

Comment: Take off the joins (since you are only using them to filter) and see if the sum works on the base table.

Comment: Did that and now its throwing a pop up box asking for StartTime and EndTime. Doesn't make sense tho since they are from volunteers and we have already added v.StartTime to it.

Comment: I see now, I changed v for volunteers and starttime is in Vol_Tasks (was vt now x).  change it to x.StartTime, x.EndTime

Comment: Haha wow I should have seen that. Now its just asking for a second value and when I put in a value it just says that its not a good expression.

Comment: well, just check all of the fields again, without me seeing your tables it's just shot in the dark now...

Comment: I just don't have another variable to enter into it is the problem I think. Cause in VOL_TASKS all I have is Name, TaskCode, StartTime, and EndTime